# Schedule a batch to ping at system startup and check if it's running from task manager

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, scheduled-tasks

using system scheduler on win 2012R2 I would run the following bat file:

```
echo %DATE%_%TIME% >> C:\test\testschedule.txt

timeout /T 300 /NOBREAK

start ping 8.8.8.8 -t

start ping 208.67.222.222 -t

start ping 208.67.220.220 -t
```

the script runs fine if manually executed.
the script seems to run fine if scheduled with a user with log as batch job local policy applied.
The txt file gets populated at every restart.
I would like to check if it's running on task manager (or an easy way to identify it with the equivalent of a process id written in the txt file).
Could anyone give me a tip about how getting it done?

Comment: `wmic process where "caption='cmd.exe' or caption='ping.exe'" get ProcessID, CommandLine`

Comment: thank you, and by the way, I forgot that starting the pings with: start ping, makes them visible in the task manager, so I already had a way to track them, but I like more your solution.